# CMD window presents nothing after debugging

Tags: c++

I'm on windows 10 using Microsoft Visual 2015. Here is the problem I was given:

Consider the following incomplete C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    ...
}

    A) Write a statement that includes the header files fstream, string, and 
       iomanip in this program.

    B) Write statements that declare inFile to be an ifstream variable and
       outFile to be an ofstream variable.

    C) The program will read data from the file inData.txt and write output 
       to the file outData.txt. Write statements to open both of these files, 
       associate inFile with inData.txt, and associate outFile with outData.txt.

    D) Suppose that the file inData.txt contains the following data:

            Giselle Robinson Accounting
            5600 5 30
            450 9
            75 1.5

        The first line contains a person's first name, last name, and the department 
        the person works in. In the second line, the first number represents the monthly
        gross salary, the bonus (as a percent), and the taxes (as a percent). The third
        line contains the distance traveled and the traveling time. The fourth line
        contains the number of coffee cups sold and the cost of each coffee cup. Write
        statements so that after the program executes, the contents of the file outData.txt
        are shown as below. If necessary, declare additional variables. Your statements 
        should be general enough so that if the contents of the input file changes and the 
        program is run again (without editing and recompilin), it outputs the appropriate results.

            Name : Giselle Robinson, Department : Accounting
            Monthly Gross Salary: $5600.00, Monthly Bonus: 5.00%, Taxes: 30.00%
            Paycheck: $4116.00

            Distance Traveled: 450.00 miles, Traveling Time: 9.00 hours
            Average Speed: 50.00 miles per hour

            Number of Coffee Cups Sold: 75, Cost: $1.50 per cup
            Sales Amount = $112.50

    E) Write statements that close the input and output files.

    F) Write C++ program that tests the statements in parts a through e.
```

Here is my code for the problem:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;

inFile.open("inData.txt");
outFile.open("outData.txt");

string firstName, lastName, department;

double monthlySalary, gross, bonus, tax, distance, time, cost, salesAmount,  speed;

int count;

inFile.open("inData.txt");
outFile.open("outData.txt");

inFile >> firstName >> lastName >> department;
outFile << "Name:" << firstName << "" << lastName
    << ", Department:" << department << endl;
inFile >> gross >> bonus >> tax;
outFile << "Monthly Gross Salary: $" << gross
    << ", Monthly Bonus: " << bonus << "%Taxes:" << tax << "%" << endl;

inFile >> distance >> time;
outFile << "Distance Travelled:" << distance
    << ", Traveling Time:" << time << "hours" << endl;

speed = distance / time;
outFile << "Average Speed:" << speed
    << ", miles per hour" << endl;

inFile >> count >> cost;
outFile << "Numbeer of Coffee Cups Sold:" << count
    << " Cost: $" << cost << "per cup" << endl;

monthlySalary = gross + ((gross*bonus) / 100);
monthlySalary = monthlySalary - (monthlySalary * 30) / 100;

salesAmount = count*cost;
return 0;
}
```

When I debug this in MSVS, the CMD prompt only says press any key to continue.
after some research I can only assume it has something to do with my
indata file, but I am not sure. I have created a file named that and placed it in to the same file as my outdata file, but nothing. Am I out in left field on this or in the ballpark? I should see a result such as this:

Name : Giselle Robinson, Department : Accounting
Monthly Gross Salary: $5600.00, Monthly Bonus: 5.00%, Taxes: 30.00%
Paycheck: $4116.00

Distance Traveled: 450.00 miles, Traveling Time: 9.00 hours
Average Speed: 50.00 miles per hour

Number of Coffee Cups Sold: 75, Cost: $1.50 per cup
Sales Amount = $112.50

Comment: Opening the files twice, is that intentional? Also, after opening a file should check whether that succeeded. You can use the member function `fail()` to check that.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Opening the files twice I'm not really seeing what you are referring to.

Comment: For example, you have two `inFile.open("inData.txt");` statements.

Comment: Ah crap I see what I did. I'll delete that.  As for  fail()   we haven't covered that so not sure how to use it

Answer (score 1):

You're not seeing any results because you're not printing anything. Instead, you're writing everything to `outFile`.

```
outFile << "Name:" << firstName << "" << lastName
    << ", Department:" << department << endl;
```

If you want it to show up in your console, use `cout` instead:

```
cout << "Name:" << firstName << "" << lastName
    << ", Department:" << department << endl;
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot when I get back to the house.  Question is if I change that I need  to use iostream correct?

Comment: Ok I understand that I need to change it cout, but I will get an undeclared identifier with it. If I declare it, it should be changed at outfile.open ("openData.txt") to what?

Comment: And I think if I do that it deviates from what the problem is asking me to do.   Write statements that declare inFile to be an ifstream variable and outFile to be an ofstream variable.
The program will read data from the file inData.txt and write output to the file outData.txt. Write statements to open both of these files, associate inFile with inData.txt, and associate outFile with outData.txt.